# How to take image by detect face frame in xamarin form

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

i perform take image from by click the `Take Picture` button and `captured image`.

But now i want to take image by adding this frame when face is right within circle than frame should be green and take a picture automatically. first time it should be red.how to add this frame in `xamarin` project? you can see image.

[image]

Comment: You will have to make custom renderers for Both iOS and Android using native API's and then make custom controls for both

Answer (score 1):

According to detecting face, I suggest you can take a look Google's Mobile Vision, adding the **Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Vision** NuGet package. it provides a set of APIs for “Detecting Face”, “Recognizing Text”, and “Scanning Barcodes”.

[Adding Face Tracking and Live Recognition to your Android App](https://blog.xamarin.com/adding-face-tracking-live-recognition-android-app/)

MultiProcessor requires an implementation of IFactory to callback when a human Face is detected in the camera.

The FaceGraphic instance is created when a Face is detected the first time, updated as the face changes, and hidden when the face goes out of the frame. Then you can call take photo method to take image autimatically in OnUpdate.

You can use Bool flag to control taking image if you have token image already.